# Create Class objects based on type signature

Tags: java

```
Class.forName(boolean.class.getName());
```

This doesn't work in Java - the virtual machine slaps you with a ClassNotFoundException. I was in need for something like that because I wanted to reflect methods based on Strings that included the method signatures, like

```
public void doSomething(boolean yesWeCan, java.lang.String[] presidents);
```

At the end I came up with a custom 'ClassFactory' which translates the type Strings to class objects. This factory includes a lot of handlers for primitive and array type values.

The handler for array type objects is something like:

```
if (isArrayOfObjects) {
   return Class.forName("L["+typeName.replace("[]", "")+";");
}
```

My question is - have I missed something in the Java 1.5+ API that might do the trick?

**Edit**

Thanks for your answers, it's not a surprise that `Class.forName` works pretty well with the wrapper classes. But I'm looking for a solution for all java types, including arrays and primitives. Thus my first line is not a typo. Some method signatures do have java primitives as parameters, I can't just use a wrapper class to reflect the method in a library, I really need the Class object for that type (like boolean).

```
Class<boolean> booleanClassObject = boolean.class;
```

works fine, as well as

```
String name = boolean.class.getName();
```

Comment: `boolean` is a primitive datatype, `Boolean` (note the capital B) is the class. You have to use the class.

Comment: He's trying to use Boolean.TYPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have a number of `if`s:

```
if (type.equals("boolean")) {
    return boolean.class;
} else if (type.equals("int")) {
    return int.class;
} .. etc
```

Comment: That's like in my actual ClassFactory. If I didn't miss something obvious in the Java API, then I stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
Class.forName(Boolean.class.getName());
```

Auto(un)boxing should handle the translation to actual primitive. Although without seeing more of your code I can't be sure if this solves your problem.

Comment: Good idea - but then I get a `Class<java.lang.Boolean>` object, but I need a `Class<boolean>` as a result (in this example).

Comment: @Andreas: boolean (with a small b) is not a class and can never be instantiated in that manner. This is (partly) the reason for the Boolean class (and other comparable primitives classes). It would be helpful if you provided a more complete code example. That might allow users to suggest an alternate approach.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I don't want to instantiate any primitive java type. I need to invoke methods (or, to be more precise, just check if the declared methods are present in libraries) and therefore I need to pass the method parameter types as a `Class[]`. So if a method has a `boolean` parameter (`"boolean"` qould be my input value), I need the `boolean.class` object.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to actually create an array, and then ask for its .class. That's what I've done in the past.

Comment: ... so stick with the 'factory' solution, backed by a lookup table for primitives (mine has a dozen if statements right now)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the Boolean wrapper class instead of the primitive boolean?

Comment: He wants Boolean.TYPE, not Boolean.class.

Comment: I need `boolean.class` as a result for the input `"boolean"` (and the same for all java types, like `String[].class` for `"String[]"`)

Answer (score 0):

You  are using boolean which is a primitive in java. You must use Boolean which is **wrappaer** class in java.

Comment: I can't use Boolean in this case, because I need `boolean.class`, not `java.lang.Boolean.class`

Answer (score 0):

```
primitive type is a object and  not a class.  it can't getClassLoader and  getClassName.
the below expression will be wrong.
boolean a = new boolean();
```

Comment: `boolean.class` is valid and is a Class object.